# I need help understanding LINQ. Where is my understanding going wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'll give you my best attempt at understanding it and you let me know where I'm going wrong.

For simplicity, let's assume that we live in a word that only has

- numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`
- operators `%`, `>` with their usual precdence

I want to dissamble what happens when I do

```
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered = from i in All
                            where i % 2 == 1
                            orderby i descending
                            select i; 
foreach ( var i in Filtererd ) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

What I understand first of all is that the query itself does not create a `Ienumerable<int>`; it creates and [Expression Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) associated with the query. The elements returned by the query are `yield`ed in an invisible function created by the compiler like

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyInvisibleFunction ( List<int> Source )
{
    foreach ( int i in Source.Reverse() )
    {
       if ( i % 2 == 1 ) 
       {
           yield return i;
       } 
    }
}
```

(Of course that's kind of a weird example because `Source.Reverse()` is itself a query, but anyways ...)

Now I'm confused where expression tress come into play here. When I think of expression trees, I think of trees like

```
        (3 % 1 > 0)
          /      \ 
         /        \   
     (3 % 1)  >    0
      /   \ 
     3  %  1
```

in the small world I've created. But where does a tree like that come in to play in my LINQ query

```
from i in All
where i % 2 == 1
orderby i descending
select i
```

??? That's what I don't understand. I'm looking at the [Expression class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) and I see how it could create the example tree I showed, but I don't see where it would come into play in my query.

Comment: Expression trees don't come into play in your query, because your source is a regular in-memory list. Expression trees are useful when your source is something like a SQL database and LINQ needs to translate your query to SQL.

Comment: I am not sure how to even begin describing everything that is wrong with your beliefs about LINQ.  Stop believing all that stuff because it is all wrong. My advice is that you obtain a copy of the C# specification and carefully read the section on the LINQ transformations.

Comment: Since Hillary Clinton doesn't even know what wiping a server (with a cloth) means, I'm pretty sure you're not Hillary Clinton.  Your user name is being discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319809/what-is-the-policy-on-user-names-that-are-obvious-impersonators-of-actual-person).  Personally, I'd consider changing your user name to something else before I or one of the other mods does it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'll give you my best attempt at understanding it and you let me know where I'm going wrong.

OK.

> What I understand first of all is that the query itself does not create a `Ienumerable<int>`;

This statement is completely wrong.

> it creates and Expression Tree associated with the query.

This statement is also completely wrong.

> The elements returned by the query are yielded in an invisible function created by the compiler

This statement is also completely wrong.

> where does a tree like that come in to play in my LINQ query

It doesn't. Your query uses no expression trees.

> I'm looking at the Expression class and I see how it could create the example tree I showed, but I don't see where it would come into play

It doesn't.

> want to dissamble what happens when I do

```
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered = from i in All
                        where i % 2 == 1
                        orderby i descending
                        select i; 
foreach ( var i in Filtererd ) 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Let's break it down. First the compiler turns that into

```
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered = All.Where(i => i % 2 == 1).OrderBy(i => i);                          
foreach ( var i in Filtererd ) 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Next the compiler does overload resolution and evaluates extension methods

```
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered = 
  Enumerable.OrderBy<int>(
    Enumerable.Where<int>(All, i => i % 2 == 1)), 
    i => i));                           
foreach ( var i in Filtererd ) 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Next lambdas are desugared:

```
static bool A1(int i) { return i % 2 == 1; )
static int A2(int i) { return i }
...
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered = 
  Enumerable.OrderBy<int>(
    Enumerable.Where<int>(All, new Func<int, bool>(A1))), 
    new Func<int, int>(A2)));                           
foreach (var i in Filtererd ) 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

That is actually not how the lambdas are desugared exactly; they are also cached, but let's ignore that detail.

I assume that you do not want the foreach desugared. See the C# specification for details.

If you want to know what Where and OrderBy do, read the source code.

Comment: Now we know why lambdas are so darn sweet and tastey. As always, excellent reference Mr. Lippert.

Comment: I think you meant to use `OrderByDescending` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

> Expression trees don't come into play in your query, because your source is a regular in-memory list. – Theodoros Chatzigiannakis

This is true.

There is no invisible iterator function being generated. Your query translates to:

```
List<int> All = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> Filtered =
 All
 .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
 .OrderByDescending(i => i);
```

There is no need for custom iterators. The language just calls the existing library functions.

This is the same for `IQueryable` except that the lambda arguments are not passed as delegates but as expression trees.

You can see this in action by commenting in the `AsQueryable()` call [here](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AMpAI457TxJrrEDCA9gDZuoDGyYLEIYgHFUEVACcwXHAAdgAIzZSYXNgEMQIGExgBvbDEMw5i5QDcWYACYwAsgAoAlHoNG35FAB5IyAHwwAQQ4YAF4YMQB3GA9kbwg/PRgARgAaGAAmNIBmNIAWNIBWGABfHABJAFEIYHQJNUVUOISAMTA2NHFUGzCAM3EWdBgwIYhAjgB6ceIAkABFYAkEes4nVzd1jc23CIALCVQhmABSDNCwpLWtq62WcSsJeQRD+5AuUSt8S+vvoxBUTh4Q0wMGwPVuqDUXB2MHsMDManEh0gMFa7X2Nmc2H0RlYAnYqGIAHVJGhyGJ7GBHDhipcacUgA).

Comment: In a sense there is *an invisible iterator function* (stretching its definition to *something internal that iterates*), the `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`. But of course the message is that `Enumerable` extension methods are plain CLR code, and that `Queryable` extension methods add this abstraction layer of expressions that can be compiled/converted into "anything".

Comment: This is true but also note that the C# language does not require queries to run over IEnumerable at all. You can write from x in y select x + 1 as long as y has a Select method. So you could add a Select extension to `bool` if you wanted to and query over it. AFAIK this has no useful applications.

Comment: Also `from b in true ...`!